# Livecycle remove first page

Tags: javascript, acrobat, livecycle

I have a LiveCycle form in Designer that has a flowable menu page with checkboxes. When a checkbox is checked, certain pages are 'shown' in the document. The pages are subforms containing an image.

This functionality works fine. What I want to do is add a button to the front page that will remove the front page, open a 'saveas' window and then close. I can get the saveas and the close function to work but the front page gets cleared and is left blank in the document. If there is nothing on the page then surely it should realise it is not required as per the workflow?

Any workarounds would be greatly appreciated, this has been doing my head in for weeks! I know I can't delete the page using the acrobat model as there aren't the correct permissions. I'm hoping a bit of javascript on the button will do the trick.

At the moment I have:

```
this.resolveNode ("indexSub").presence = "hidden";  //indexSub is the subform
app.execMenuItem("SaveAs");
app.execMenuItem("Close");
```

I will look at forcing a filename at save another time!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is quite strange behaviour. I've checked that you can set presence either to *invisible* or  *inactive* and it works fine then.

```
this.resolveNode ("indexSub").presence = "invisible";  // or "inactive"
```

Differences between *invisible* and *inactive* you can fnd here: http://blogs.adobe.com/formfeed/2009/03/xfa_30_presenceinactive.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. "inactive" looks interesting but doesn't make any difference for what I'm trying to do. The page I'm trying to make disappear is the same page that contains the trigger button. When pressed the page clears, opens SaveAs, and then Close. Since the whole subform is changing state I would expect there to be nothing left on the page but there must be something that is stopping the rest of the document from reflowing to fill the space. Back to the books...

Answer (score 0):

Actually "inactive" did play a part in the solution, not entirely sure if it was intentional!

The main change was to alter the first page from flowable to positioned. When the button was pressed, the page cleared, the SaveAs dialogue opened and then the document closed. When the saved document was reopened the menu page had disappeared as required. I'll add a comment to this if anything changes. Thanks all.